# AutoMapper map Dictionary with the help of injected service

Tags: c#, dictionary, dependency-injection, automapper

I need something like this:

```
    public myMappingProfile(IInjectableService myInjectableService)
    {
        CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.DestinationDictionary, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
            {
                var dict = new Dictionary<myEnum, string>();
                foreach (var item in src.SourceDictionary)
                {
                    dict.Add(item.Key, myInjectableService.BuildUrl(item.Value));
                }
                return dict;
            }));
```

Dependency Injection of the service works fine. But Visual Studio shows the following error message:

> A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an
>   expression tree

Then I changed the destination type from Dictionary to List> and tried to use the AfterMap method:

```
           .ForMember(dest => dest.DestinationListOfKeyValuePair, opt => opt
           .MapFrom(src => src.SourceDictionary))
           .AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.DestinationListOfKeyValuePair
           .ForEach(ti => ti.Value = myInjectableService.BuildUrl(ti.Value)));
```

But Visual Studio complains:

> Property or indexer cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Next try was a CustomResolver:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.TenantImages, opt => opt.MapFrom<CustomResolver>())
```

public class CustomResolver : IValueResolver>>
    {
        private readonly IInjectableService _myInjectableService;

```
    public CustomResolver(IInjectableService myInjectableService)
    {
        _myInjectableService = myInjectableService;
    }

    public List<KeyValuePair<MyEnum, string>> Resolve(
        Source source,
        Destination destination,
        List<KeyValuePair<MyEnum, string>> destMember,
        ResolutionContext context)
    {
        destMember = new List<KeyValuePair<MyEnum, string>>();
        foreach (var entry in source.SourceDictionary)
        {
            destMember.Add(new KeyValuePair<myEnum, string>(entry.Key, _myInjectableService.BuildUrl(entry.Value)));
        }
        return destMember;
    }
}
```

But the followin exception is thrown:

> System.MissingMethodException : No parameterless constructor defined
>   for this object.

I don't know how to put the IInjectableService into the CustomResolver.

Any ideas how to solve this issue?
Thank you.

Comment: See [this](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to use [`.ConvertUsing()`](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html):

```
    // Add this mapping, if the name of the property in source and destination type differ.
    CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.DestinationDictionary, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SourceDictionary));

    // Add this mapping to create an instance of the dictionary, filled by the values from the source dictionary.
    CreateMap</*type of source dictionary*/, Dictionary<myEnum, string>>()
        .ConvertUsing(src =>
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<myEnum, string>();
            foreach (var item in src)
            {
                dict.Add(item.Key, myInjectableService.BuildUrl(item.Value));
            }
            return dict;
        }));
```

Additionally you can bring your dictionary creation down to a LINQ one liner:

```
src.ToDictionary(item => item.Key, item => myInjectableService.BuildUrl(item.Value));
```